# Three people each choose five distinct numbers at random from the numbers 1, 2, . . . , 25, independently of each other.

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

*What is the probability that the three choices of five numbers have no number in common?*

I know I have to use inclusion-exlcuion here and that using the compliment is probably the best way to solve this.  I can't really think of what the events should be though.

My first thought is to let $A_{i}$ = the event that all three pick the number $i$.  This would be a pretty tedious inclusion-exclusion problem though so I was wondering if this is the right set of events to use for this problem or if not, what the right set of events is.

**EDIT** I know the answer is 0.8109

**EDIT** I came up with an answer that gets me to the answer in the back of the book and I am 99% sure it's right
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{5} (-1)^{i+1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ i \end{pmatrix} \cdot \frac{\begin{pmatrix} 25 - i \\ 5 - i \end{pmatrix}^{3}}{\begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}^{3}}
$$

Comment: Where did you get 0.8109? Think about it. The last person to choose must choose all their numbers avoiding 10 out of the 25 available. The chance of choosing just one number out so that it avoids the 10 already chosen is 0.6. The chance of all five avoiding the 10 already chosen must be even less.

Comment: The answer is in the back of the book. It could be wrong. All three people are making their picks without any knowledge of what the other person is picking.  Imagine them all simultaneously picking 5 distinct numbers between 1 through 25.  So it's not like person 1 has 25 choices, person 2 has 20 choices, and person 3 has 15 choices.

Comment: Sure, each person ${25\choose5}$ choices, but only some of those will result in all the choices being disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't have to use "inclusion-exclusion" principle to solve this.
Just use the fact that, $Probabbility=\frac{Total\ accepted\ outcomes}{Total\ outcomes}$.

The total accepted outcomes turns out to be: $(^{25}_5)(^{20}_5)(^{15}_5)$. And,

Total outcome will be: $\{(^{25}_5)\}^3$.

Thus your answer is, $Probabbility=\frac{(^{25}_5)(^{20}_5)(^{15}_5)}{\{(^{25}_5)\}^3}$

Comment: I had a similar thought at first, but it has to be thought of as person 1's choices have no impact on person 2's choices, etc.  Imagine the three people writing down 5 unique numbers between 1 and 25 on a piece of paper at the same time.  Each person has 25 choose 5 options.

Comment: @BillHamilton: Right -- that's why each of the $\binom{25}{5}^3$ possible outcomes are equally linkely, so you can use simple counting to find the probability.

Comment: @BillHamilton Yes, each person does have $25$ options from which to choose. But to be successful, they cannot randomly select their $5$ numbers, or they could have overlap (which is not desired). It is correct to compute the number of options left for every person, which Abhijit A J does here.

Answer (score 1):

The second person has ${25\choose5}$ ways of picking five numbers. ${20\choose5}$ of these will have no number in common with the first person. The third person also has ${25\choose5}$ ways of picking five numbers. ${15\choose5}$ of these will have no number in common with either of the first two. So the required prob is $$\frac{{20\choose5}{15\choose5}}{{25\choose5}^2}\approx1.6\%$$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{{25\choose 5}{20\choose 5} {15 \choose 5}}{{25 \choose 5}^3}$
is the probability that there is no number that is chosen by two or more people

$1-\sum_{i=1}^{5}(-1)^{i+1}{25\choose i} \frac{{25-i\choose 5-i}^3}{{25\choose 5}^3}$ 
is the probability that there is no number that is chosen by each of the three people